# iOS Webkit ignoring media queries

Tags: ios, css, webkit, mobile-safari, media-queries

I'm working on a website ([villa-antonia](http://www.villa-antonia.com/nueva)) using mobile-first development approach. That is, I CSS for mobile first and then add/overwrite styles with media queries for higher resolutions.
The thing is, in iPhone, a background image is loading on top of everything, in spite of being inside a media query for a higher resolution.

This is part of the CSS file (the part I think is involved):

```
body {
  background: #c70000;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

/* Minimum width of 960 pixels. */
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {

  body {
    background: transparent url('images/bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

In my understanding of CSS, iPhone shouldn't even load the bg.jpg image because is inside the media query. But this is what I get when I scroll a bit downwards:

[image: villa-antonia seen from an iPhone 5]

The car you see is part of the bg.jpg, the more I scroll downwards the more bg.jpg it shows in screen.

I really don't know why is loading the image… any ideas?

PS: The same happens in iPad and iPhone 4 (and all the other devices that can be tested at the iOS simulator).

Comment: Don't know if that matters, but the iPhone 4 has a resolution of 640×960, so in landscape your media query will apply (I know the screenshot is portrait, it's just a hint).

Comment: Does this only happen in iOS4? If so, it can be easily remedied, I don't see why it would behave this way in older iOS devices

Comment: @Linus_Caldwell my tryouts have only been in portrait, that's why in my code I haven't considered landscape. First I want to solve this situation and then I'll try landscape. But thanks for the hint.

Comment: @andres-ilich with iOS4 you mean iPhone 4? If that so, I've tried with all the hardware possibilities in the iOS Simulator. This is: iPhone, iPhone retina (3,5 inches) and iPhone Retina (4inches)

Answer (score 7):

By default iOS browsers supply a set of default screen dimensions, regardless of actual screen res *or orientation*.

In order to get them to supply the actual screen dimensions there is a Meta tag they will obey:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

If you add this to your page(s) then your @media commands should work with the actual screen values of each device.

### I found these links useful:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag
- http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok. As I thought the solution was simple and had nothing to do with the CSS media queries >.<

It was so long ago since I coded the first prototype of the website that I didn't remember that I was loading the bg.jpg image throught a javascript statement using anystretch as a fallback of backgroun-size:cover;.

Thank you all for your answers and time.